# Update Multidimentional Array with another Array for existing Keys PHP

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have two arrays: 
('admin','admin2', 'admin3' can be too many, and names can also differ other than 'admin')

```
$old = array(
array('admin'=>array('a'=>'aaa','b'=>'bbb')),
array('admin2'=>array('c'=>'ccc','d'=>'ddd'))
);

$new = array(
array('admin2'=>array('e'=>'eee','f'=>'fff')),
array('admin3'=>array('g'=>'ggg','h'=>'hhh'))
);
```

I want to have this array from both above arrays:
(new array with all different keys in both PLUS similar keys from new array)

```
$output = array(
array('admin'=>array('a'=>'aaa','b'=>'bbb')),
array('admin2'=>array('e'=>'eee','f'=>'fff')),
array('admin3'=>array('g'=>'ggg','h'=>'hhh'))
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Remove one level of array to make arrays as ['admin'=>array, 'admin2'=>array]
$old1 = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $old);
$new1 = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $new);
// Make replacement
$ready =  array_replace($old1, $new1);
// Return level making every item as array 
$result = array();
foreach($ready as $k=>&$v) 
    $result[] = array($k=>$v);
print_r($result);
```

[demolink](https://eval.in/576174)

Comment: It is working fine but I need a simpler solution, If no one posted a simple solution then I will surely Select your answer.

Comment: I don't think that with such structure of array it can be easy. But, maybe

Answer (score 1):

This code will solve your problem :

```
<?php 
$array1 = array(
    array('admin'=>array('a'=>'aaa','b'=>'bbb')),
    array('admin2'=>array('c'=>'ccc','d'=>'ddd'))
);

$array2 = array(
    array('admin2'=>array('e'=>'eee','f'=>'fff')),
    array('admin3'=>array('g'=>'ggg','h'=>'hhh'))
);

$output = $array1; ///merge array1 into output array

foreach($array2 as $key => $val)
{
    $is_present_key = false;
    $first_key = key($val);
    foreach($output as $k => $v)
    {
        if(array_key_exists($first_key,$output[$k])) ////check if key exit in $output array
        {
            $output[$k] = $val; ///push new value if key exists in $output
            $is_present_key = true;
        }
    }
    if($is_present_key == false)///skip for duplicate of new values if key exists in $output 
    {
        $output[] = $val;
    }
}

echo "<pre>"; print_r($output);

?>
```

This will give you :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [admin] => Array
                (
                    [a] => aaa
                    [b] => bbb
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [admin2] => Array
                (
                    [e] => eee
                    [f] => fff
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [admin3] => Array
                (
                    [g] => ggg
                    [h] => hhh
                )

        )

)
```

***[LIVE EXAMPLE](https://eval.in/576210)***

Answer (score 0):

```
$old = array(
  array('admin'=>array('a'=>'aaa','b'=>'bbb')),
  array('admin2'=>array('c'=>'ccc','d'=>'ddd'))
);

$new = array(
  array('admin2'=>array('e'=>'eee','f'=>'fff')),
  array('admin3'=>array('g'=>'ggg','h'=>'hhh'))
);

$arr=array_merge($new,$old);
$new_arr=array();
foreach($arr as $key=>$val){
    foreach($val as $k=>$v){
        if(array_key_exists($k, $new_arr)){
            continue;
        }else{
            $new_arr[$k]=$v;
        }
    }
}
echo "<pre>";print_r($new_arr); echo "</pre>";
```